# Ubuntu 18 Intellij Shortcut Conflict

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-18.04

Recently almost all my intellij shorctuts (defaults) stopped working. For example F9 which is a shortcut for "Resume program" currently shows all windows side by side. I've already tried solutions proposed in similar threads, I've looked into keyboard settings and did not found any conflicts there. I've also used dconf editor in order to make sure I did not miss anything - no luck there either. Any idea what may cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - as it turned out my FN key was in always ON mode.